# bashrc function to add a specific ssh key to the current terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent

In order not to have to type the passphrase for every single `git` command I use to fetch/pull/push code from a remote machine I'm logged onto, to git{lab|hub}, I added this [alias](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/) in my `.bashrc` file:

```
alias='eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add'
```

This works fine on machines where there is one and only one ssh key in the `~/.ssh` folder, or if the ssh key to use is named after the default key taken into account by `ssh-add` as stated by the doc:

> ssh-add adds private key identities to the authentication agent, ssh-agent(1).
> When run without arguments, it adds the files ~/.ssh/id_rsa, ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, and ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ssh-add.1.html

But now, I'm on a machine where I have more than one ssh key (it's probably overkill but it's like that):

```
$ cd ~/.ssh && ls -l 
-rw------- 1 user user 6059 jun  9 10:18 config
-rw------- 1 user user 9546 jul  1 17:58 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 user user 1417 aug 20 20:20 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 user user 1424 jan 14 09:55 id_ed25519
-rw------- 1 user user 1424 jan 14 09:55 id_ed25519.pub
-rw------- 1 user user 1401 feb 16 13:26 id_ed25519-github
-rw------- 1 user user 1401 feb 16 13:26 id_ed25519-github.pub
-rw------- 1 user user  808 apr  2 12:22 id_ed25519-gitlab
-rw------- 1 user user  808 apr  2 12:22 id_ed25519-gitlab.pub
```

So, I would like to be able to pass the name of the key as a parameter to my `ssh-eval` alias.

I though building a function would be the way to go but it's not working as expected as it's actually starting an infinite amount of `ssh-agent` processes (I have to Ctrl+C the command to actually stop it starting these processes) when I launch it (after having `source ~/.bashrc`):

```bash
ssh-eval() {
    eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add "$1"
}

export -f ssh-eval
```

Which I then call either like:

```
ssh-eval ~/.ssh/id_ed25519-github
```

or

```
ssh-eval
```

Both are spawning ssh-agent processes infinitely (I have to force stop it using Ctrl+C).

How could I do that properly and securely?

Comment: You should only run `eval $(ssh-agent)` once - for example in your `.bashrc`. Then you can run `ssh-add` however you like. Also, how do you call your function? Do you pass the complete path to your keyfile, or just the name?

Comment: Original question updated to answer your questions. And thanks for the first hint.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Your function spawns exactly one `ssh-agent` per invocation on my machine (Arch Linux). Could you be calling this function multiple times by mistake?

Comment: Do you still have any aliases or other functions defined that might be interfering (e.g. for `ssh-agent`, `ssh-eval`, or `ssh-add`)?

Comment: No, it's the only one, the only other function is dealing with some `git` command to fetch and update a master branch in one shot, no ssh is involved there.